# FC-MORE fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to remove the fc-more tag from fullcalendar for the current day in month view?  Ex: the previous day still have the possibility of having the button of more events and the current day not having the button

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. The "more" button appears depending on the number of events in the day, not related to which day it is.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further. What exactly you want to accomplish. The scenario might require custom programming. But first your scenario should be clear?